# Is there a PowerShell Command that can change the gpedit setting to Restrict Remote Desktop users to a single session?

Tags: remote-desktop, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I have to set up servers often, and am developing a base setup script to configure our group's most standard practices.

We often have to enable more than one session for a remote user. So what I'm wondering is if I can script disabling the policy "Restrict Remote Desktop Services users to a single Remote Desktop Services session" Found in

> gpedit.msc -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Remote Desktop Services -> Remote Desktop Sessions Host -> Connections.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most GP settings are simply registry entries/changes.

Microsoft offers documentation that tells you which Registry setting aligns to which Group Policy:

[Group Policy Settings Reference for Windows and Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=25250)

Looking in the Windows Server 2012 R2 document, it shows that

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services!fSingleSessionPerUser`

Is the registry entry that holds the data you are looking to set.

You can change the registry with Powershell by using its standard registry handling commandlets.

More info on that: [Weekend Scripter: Use PowerShell to Easily Modify Registry Property Values](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/05/12/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-easily-modify-registry-property-values.aspx)

Comment: Cool thanks, because I looked at fSingleSessionPerUser according to some other sources and it was set, while the gpedit setting disabled. But I did not look in `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\\`*`Policies`*. When I looked under that branch, fSingleSessionPerUser is *off*.